# How is Canvas getImageData object manipulated from an independent variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I was going through a canvas manipulation tutorial to change color of each pixel and I came across the following code (also written below): http://www.qoncious.com/questions/changing-brightness-image-html5-canvas

How is it that the final `context.putImageData` works fine with `iD` object (which we didn't touch, we only manipulated `dA` array) ?

```
var iD = context.getImageData(imgX, imgY, img.width, img.height);
var dA = iD.data; // raw pixel data in array

var brightnessMul = 1.35; // brightness multiplier

for(var i = 0; i < dA.length; i += 4)
{
var red = dA[i]; // Extract original red color [0 to 255]
var green = dA[i + 1]; // Extract green
var blue = dA[i + 2]; // Extract blue

brightenedRed = brightnessMul * red;
brightenedGreen = brightnessMul * green;
brightenedBlue = brightnessMul * blue;

/**
  *
  * Remember, you should make sure the values brightenedRed,
  * brightenedGreen, and brightenedBlue are between
  * 0 and 255. You can do this by using
  * Math.max(0, Math.min(255, brightenedRed))
  *
  */

dA[i] = brightenedRed;
dA[i + 1] = brightenedGreen;
dA[i + 2] = brightenedBlue;
}

context.putImageData(iD, imgX, imgY);
```

I've checked, the code works fine, but how is it that a change in `dA` automatically changes `iD` (I expect `iD` and `dA` to be independent variables)?

Comment: Nope. `data` is a property of the `imageData` object so they are intrinsically connected. Totally off-topic, but are you the golfer? -- If yes, props to your career!

Comment: iD.data is probably a reference type and not a primitive type. Take a look at this examples (http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch04_04.htm) and you will get the difference.

Comment: Yeah, when you bind a variable to a property of an object, you're creating a reference to that property, as opposed to creating a separate copy of it. Anything done to `dA` is actually having a direct effect on the `iD.data` object to which it's pointing

Comment: Thanks @markE, valenz and jmcgriz. My assumption was wrong!